# How to merge multiple .mp4 file in single .mp4 ffmpeg android

Tags: android, merge, ffmpeg, mp4, concatenation

I am merging **multiple .mp4 file into single .mp4** after merging only first .mp4 is displayed properly and other video is not displayed.

I used this `ffmpeg` command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i " + strTextPath + " -c copy " + strFinalMergedVideoPath;
```

Comment: You need the use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1).

Comment: Thanx for suggestion.@Mulvya

Comment: Check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321420/pause-resume-with-android-mediarecorder-api-level-24/51578748#51578748